# gRPC connection error "CaUsedAsEndEntity" using Rust Tonic

Tags: go, rust, grpc, bitcoin, lightning-network

I've been having some problem connecting to an [LND](https://docs.lightning.engineering/lightning-network-tools/lnd) node running on [Polar](https://lightningpolar.com/).
I keep constantly getting this error:

`tonic::transport::Error(Transport, hyper::Error(Connect, Custom { kind: InvalidData, error: InvalidCertificate(Other(CaUsedAsEndEntity)) }))'`

this code that I'm using for that:

```
#[tokio::main]
async fn main() {
    // build our application with a single route
    let app = Router::new().route("/", get(|| async { "Hello, World!" }));

    let cert = Certificate::from_pem(include_bytes!("<route-to>/lnd/alice/tls.cert"));

    let tls_conf: ClientTlsConfig = ClientTlsConfig::new().domain_name("localhost").ca_certificate(cert);

    let channel =  tonic::transport::Channel::from_static("https://127.0.0.1:10001").tls_config(tls_conf).unwrap().connect().await.unwrap();

    // run it with hyper on localhost:3000
    axum::Server::bind(&"0.0.0.0:3000".parse().unwrap())
        .serve(app.into_make_service())
        .await.unwrap();
}
```

please advice. This is getting crazy hahaha, I actually checked out the code from [lncli](https://github.com/lightninglabs/lightning-terminal) but got confused on what is being done with TLS